# How can I grep gmail in the terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, email, terminal, gmail

I've been thinking of doing this for weeks, so someone else must want it too.

#### Places I've looked:

1. https://developers.google.com/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed: This seems promising, but I haven't taken the time to muck around with it thoroughly and get it working
2. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python: ditto to 1.
3. https://github.com/rgs1/gmail-cli: Haven't tried; don't have time right now; also looks promising
4. https://gist.github.com/Altech/4015832: maybe I have an old version of ruby.  I run `ruby search_gmail.rb` and get this error

   ```
   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- gmail (LoadError)
   from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
   from search_gmail.rb:4:in `<main>'
   ```
5. https://linuxconfig.org/check-your-gmail-inbox-for-new-emails-with-bash-script:  "works" but only gives me the most recent inbox titles.  If someone who's really good with sed, awk, grep, etc. could post how to turn this into an arbitrary grep search, that would be much appreciated

If I have a free moment and figure this out, I'll post it later.  But either way, a comprehensive guide to this should be somewhere on the internet, and I haven't found it with cursory Google searches.  Hence my asking this question

Comment: I'm sure someone on SO can answer this.  But I'd expect a better answer from https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: SO recommends (almost requires) that questions respect a certain format, please, take some time to read [how to ask useful questions aka MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @LuisMuñoz thank you.  Afraid I'm not sure which part you're pointing at, exactly.  I'm on the linked page.  Should I post more detail about what I've done in each of the 5 methods?

Comment: Yes, pick the one you like and present it as a Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example and then make a concrete question or show a problem about what you are trying to do.

Comment: FYI, I just tried this using curl and oauth 2 w/ gmail's inbox feed:  `https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom`.  They said you have to have a premium "G Suite domain" account (business account).  And when I tried it I got a warning from Gmail that they would block access due to lower security.  As for me, I am not messing with this.